# Given a network switch, can we identify the devices (IP not assigned yet) connected to it?

Tags: network, network-core, network-discovery

If IP is not assigned to the server yet and suppose it is connected to a switch, then can we still get the details of the server from the switch?

Comment: What kind of details are you looking for?

Comment: Switches are transparent devices that only inspect the MAC addresses on frames that pass through them.

Comment: ... however beware the term "level 3 switch", which is best thought of as a pure ("level 2") switch and a router in the same box, which can be switched on in the configuration.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you can get the server to generate some traffic, you can determine the manufacturer of the NIC card from the OUI portion of the MAC address.   That isn't the same as the server manufacturer, but often, it's a good clue.

Comment: You mean to say, If the server is able to put some data packet on the network and if that reaches the switch, switch will then register the Mac address of the server?

Comment: Actually we are looking at discovering a server. In our use case, there will a server with IP not assigned to it yet, and connected to a switch. But we have the switch details. Can we identify the server which is connected to the given switch and then assign IP to that?

Comment: @PavanRajan, you don't assign an IP address to a server that way. The server itself either has an IP address statically assigned in its configuration, or it requests assignment from a DHCP server, and it either accepts or rejects the offered address from the DHCP server responding to the DHCP request that it made.

Comment: @PavanRajan Assuming you mean to discover a new server with a default configuration, you can do this, although it's a little convoluted.  You will need to set up a DHCP server to assign IP addresses to your new servers.

Answer (score 2):

Which information the switch has about a connected client depends on what the client is transmitting.

First of, *any* frame transmitted carries the client's MAC address as source and updates the switch's MAC table (from the switch's POV a server is just a client node). Often, this will be the DHCP recovery for a dynamically assigned IP address but it could be anything. Servers often have static IP addresses assigned locally, so in that case the first frame might be an ARP response. As Ron's already pointed out, the MAC address most often reveals the server or NIC manufacturer.

Switches with active port authentication can learn quite a bit more about the client unless they just pass on the authentication information.

Everything else has to be voluntarily sent by the client, including various discovery protocols like LLDP - if the switch supports these protocols.